# Precision accuracy in Matlab

Tags: matlab, precision, logistic-regression

I'm trying to implement a Logistic Regression algorithm, and part of the Matlab code is as follows.

```
for i = 1 : MAX_ITR
    % Calculate mu
    mu = 1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-(X * w)));

    % Calculate h to check for convergence
    h(i) = sum(-y .* log(mu) - (1 - y) .* log(1 - mu)) + (lambda / 2) * norm(w([2:end]))^2;

    % Calculate gradient and hessian.
    G = lambda .* w; 
    G(1) = 0;       % Set extra term for gradient to 0
    L = lambda .* eye(D + 1); 
    L(1) = 0;       % Set extra term for Hessian to 0
    grad = (X' * (mu - y)) + G;
    S = diag((mu .* (1 - mu)));
    H = (X' * S * X) + L;

    % Update w
    w = w - H\grad;
end
```

Obviously the value of `mu` cannot be 1, since the exponential cannot be 0. However, there are certain values where the exponential evaluates to a very small value, such as `1.6629e-05`. This causes my `mu` value for that instance to be very close to 1, i.e. 0.999983371689452.

I've ran the code iteration by iteration, and the first 4 iterations are fine as `mu` does not contain any such "close-to-1" value. However, the fifth iteration does, and as a result, I get a `NaN` for my `h`, and the algorithm won't converge.

I've ran the `digits` command and its value is 32, so I don't know what is causing this problem.

**ETA**:
Updated code after @rayryeng's suggestion:
`D` is the number of features in `X`, `m` is the number of training samples `X`

```
   for i = 1 : MAX_ITR
        % Initialize arrays
        grad = zeros(D+1,1);
        h(i) = 0;
        H = zeros(D+1,D+1);

        for j = 1 : m
            % Calculate mu
            mu = sigmoid(X(j,:) * w);

            % Calculate h (to check for convergence)
            h(i) = h(i) - (1/m)*(y(j) * log(mu) + (1 - y(j)) * log(1 - mu)) + (lambda / (2 * m)) * norm(w(2:end))^2;

            % Calculate gradient and Hessian
            G = lambda * w; 
            G(1) = 0;       % Set extra term for gradient to 0
            L = lambda * eye(numFeatures + 1); 
            L(1) = 0;       % Set extra term for Hessian to 0
            grad = grad - (1/m) * ((X(j,:)' * (mu - y(j))) + G);
            S = diag((mu .* (1 - mu)));
            H = H - (1/m) * ((X(j,:)' * S * X(j,:)) + L);
        end
        %fprintf('h(%d) = %0.5f\n', i, h(i));

        % Update w
        w = w - H\grad;
    end
```

I don't get the `NaN` error anymore, and the `h` values seem to converge after a few iterations.

Comment: I'm assuming `w(1)` is the bias term.... but you are including it again in `X*w` when calculating the sigmoid?

Comment: I guess `NaN` is due to `(1-y).*log(1-mu)` being something like `0*inf`. Can't you write the expression of `mu` into `log(1-mu)` and simplify, to avoid loss of precision problems?

Comment: You could try using `log1p` to handle the small `mu` values: `... -(1-y).*log1p(-mu) ...`. You should look at how `y` varies as well. `digits` is for variable precision arithmetic – it's irrelevant if you're doing this in standard double precision.

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, w(1) is the bias term. I have removed it.

Comment: @Rayne -  How are you minimizing the Logistic Regression cost function? Are you using gradient descent? Some other cost minimization scheme?  BTW, did the removal of the additional bias term change anything?

Comment: @rayryeng The values of h is slightly higher with the bias terms than without. BTW, I am using a (D+1)-by-1 w vector where D is the number of features in X, and I have concatenated a '1' to every Xi vector, i.e. first feature is now '1'. I'm using Newton's method for the LR, and I'm following this page (http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex5/ex5.html) quite closely.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I could try that, although I'm hoping to keep the code clean.

Comment: @horchler I've tried `NLL(i) = sum(-ytrain .* log(mu) - (1 - ytrain) .* log1p(-mu)) + (lambda / 2) * norm(w([2:end]))^2;`, but the code still returns a `NaN` at the 5th iteration, where there is a close-to-1 value in `mu`.

Comment: @Rayne - Can you show the code you used to implement Newton's Method to minimize the cost function?  It may be that there's a bug in the implementation of your Hessian and cost function matrices.  From what I can tell, there's nothing wrong with the way you are computing the cost function.

Comment: What happens if you remove `* norm(w([2:end]))^2`?

Comment: @NKN The code still returns a `NaN` at the 5th iteration.

Comment: @NKN - That's the regularlization term.  It shouldn't matter.

Comment: @rayryeng yes but the regularization term is usually added to the main funciton, not multiplied.

Comment: @NKN it's multiplied by (lambda/2) and added to h.

Comment: @rayryeng I have added the code I've used to implement Newton's method.

Comment: right my mistake. I have my own implementation, if you want I can explain.

Comment: @NKN Sure! I'm interested to see how you've implemented it.

Comment: @Rayne - I'll debug your code later, but in the meantime, have a look at this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sitgpmu6oe2cfyt/ps1sol.pdf?dl=1 - This is the first problem assignment from Andrew Ng's CS 229 course from Autumn 2014, and pages 2-4 shows the code on how to implement Newton's Method for LR.  Compare that with your implementation and see if it matches.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @rayryeng It looks like a big difference in Andrew Ng's code is that it computes the cost function sample by sample, while I was trying to compute it all at once. However, his `grad`, `H` and `ll` are also different from mine. I tried something like this, computing the cost function sample by sample, and I don't get the `NaN` anymore! I have the results `h(1) = 0.69315, h(2) = 0.67378, h(3) = 0.67487, h(4) = 0.67488, h(5) = 0.67488, ..., h(15) = 0.67488` I'm not sure why there was a jump between h(2) and h(3) so there's probably something wrong.

Comment: I just don't quite understand why he computed the `grad`, `H` and `ll` the way he did.

Comment: @rayryeng After taking a closer look at Andrew Ng's code, I updated my code and added it to my original post.

Comment: @Rayne - Interesting... I'll have a look. Sorry for the delay.  Things are busy here.

Comment: @rayryeng No problem! I'm appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

In my implementation,

- `X` is the input data `m x n` (a column of `1`s is added to the
  initial data `X = [ones(m, 1) X];`)
- `y` is the output data.
- The initial values for thetas are 0

The sigmoid function is defined as follows:

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
    g = 1./(1+exp(-z));
end
```

The cost function is defined as follows:

```
function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)
    m = length(y);
    J = (1/m)*sum(-y .* log(sigmoid(X*theta)) - (1-y) .* log(1-sigmoid(X*theta)));
    grad = (X'*(sigmoid(X*theta)-y))/m;
end
```

In the main code, I use `fminunc` function to find the optimal theta.

```
options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400);
[theta, cost] = fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)), initial_theta, options);
```

At the end it is different than your implementation, but it might be useful to find out the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Is the (1/m) factor to sort of normalize J and grad? I was wondering why my values of h (your J) is so big.

Comment: yes it is for normalization, because you `sum` and then you need to make it normalized.

Comment: @Rayne - If you look at the document you referenced me to, they also normalize by `1/m`.

Comment: @NKN - So did I :)... I took it 3 years ago... then again recently to refresh my memory.  I love machine learning... just never had the time to get into it.

Comment: Nice! I am using it daily though. On robots!

Comment: Using a sigmoid function is a good idea. I've added that, although it didn't solve the problem. I do have another question - you have another function to look for the optimal theta. I thought once the algorithm converges, that is the theta we want? And if I want to find the predicted class (assuming 2 classes 1 or 0) for each of the samples, I could look for the `max(log p(y=1|x,theta),log p(y=0|x,theta)) = max(log (sigm(X*theta)), log (1-sigm(X*theta)))`?